# My Ubuntu runs both Unity and GNOME Shell at the same time

Tags: unity, gnome

Unity and GNOME 3 at same time

[image: Unity and GNOME 3 at same time screenshot]

My Ubuntu seems to run Unity and GNOME 3 at exactly the same time. Sure, I like it, but is there a way to remove Unity launcher?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the program unity-2d-panel is running at login, start up startup applications and uncheck it. If it doesn't appear run this from a terminal: `sudo sed -i "s/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g" /etc/xdg/autostart/*.desktop` and logout and in again before restarting startup applications.

Comment: Also greetings from a fellow imgurarian!

Comment: Thank you man, that worked perfectly. Someone must of snuck onto my laptop and added unity to startup. Ah well, it's all better now.

Comment: @Sarger001 - the way you mark the Q as solved is to click the tick mark next to the answer that helped you.